# how to get the ground truth map from ORB_SLAM

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to get the  map scale form the map which is build by ORB_slam2. Example,  there are two camera center kp1(x1-coordinate,y2-coordinate) ,   kp2(x2-coordinate,y2-coordinate), then i will know the distance between kp1 and kp2( in coordinate). But what's the real distance(m)(in the real word)?  i think i need to get the scale between coordinate and meter.  But i don't know where is the map scale in the ORB_slam2 code(now  I am a rookie ...). Could you tell me how to get the real map?? thank you very much!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233916/how-to-get-the--ground-truth-map-from-orb_slam/) by [xiqing](https://answers.ros.org/users/24127/xiqing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using Monocular, RGBD or Stereo algorithm?
ORBslam2 comes with the three approaches implemented. From a theoretical point of view, if you are using monocular approach, the map that you will obtain is not metric.

---

Originally posted by [bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/26802/bart/) with karma: 16 on 2016-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xiqing](https://answers.ros.org/users/24127/xiqing/) on 2016-05-12**:
Is that mean that i couldn't get the distance(m) if using monocular approach? What about the stereo algorithm??